# How to show $(A')'\subset A'$ In a Hausdorff space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Please how to prove that $(A')'\subset A'$ ?

We know that $$x\in (A')'\Longleftrightarrow \forall V\in \mathcal{v}_{x}, (V\setminus\{x\})\cap A'\neq\emptyset$$

How to obtain that $x\in A'$ ?

What about the other inclusion is $A'\subset (A')'$ and why ?
Thank you.

Comment: Pardon me, but what is $A'$?

Comment: It's not true unless you have some conditions on the topological space.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth mentioning that $A'$ is often called [derived set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29).

---

If $x\in A''$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then $V\setminus\{x\}$ contains some $y\in A'$. Take a neighborhood $V'$ of $y$ such that $x\notin V'$ and $V'\subseteq V$. Then $V'\setminus\{y\}\cap A\ne\emptyset$. But since $V'\subseteq V\setminus\{x\}$ we get
$$V\setminus\{x\}\cap A\ne\emptyset.$$
We have shown that if $x\in A''$ then $x\in A'$, which means that $$A''\subseteq A'.$$

---

Note that this argument works in [$T_1$-spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space). (I used existence of a neighborhood containing $y$ but not $x$.) But since your post was tagged [real-analysis](/questions/tagged/real-analysis), I assume you are mostly interested in subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Taking the 2-point discrete space and $A$ as a singleton in this space should give you an example showing that the same is not true in arbitary topological space.

---

Let us have a look at the example $$A=\{\frac1n+\frac1m; m,n=1,2,\dots\}.$$
You should get 
$$
\begin{align*}
A'&=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n; n=1,2,\dots\}\\
A''&=\{0\}
\end{align*}
$$
So you can see that $A'\subseteq A''$ is not true in general.

Comment: please how $V'$ is obtained please

Comment: @Vrouvrou As I wrote above, this argument is correct only for [$T_1$-spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space). Directly from definition of a $T_1$-space we have that for $x\ne y$ there exists and open set $V'$ such that $y\in V'$ and $x\in V$. For example, any metric space is $T_1$. (In fact it has stronger [separation properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom).) You could take ball around $y$ with radius smaller than $d(x,y)$.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify your question in the original post a bit. Are you asking whether this holds in any topological space? In any Hausdorff space? In any metric space? Or is $A$ in your question a subset of real line?